# Setting Key Bindings for Common Lisp Top Level in Emacs

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

I am currently trying to set a key binding for the `comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` command that shows REPL history in Copy-to-REPLable way.

I am doing something like this in my `.emacs`.

`(define-key global-map (kbd "M-s") 'comint-dynamic-list-input-ring)`

However, when I try `M-s` at the REPL after I define the above function, I get this warning

> Can't splice top level

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I bind this command to a key combo and have it work at the top level of SLIME's Common Lisp?

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t` and show `*Backtrace*`.

Comment: In Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp?

Comment: This is an Emacs Lisp variable: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html

Comment: `Can't splice top level` - this error looks like a message from paredit or smartparens package. it seems that those packages override your keybinding, so you need to define your keybinding after the code in those packages is executed. probably, me or someone here may provide a more detailed answer if you post a relevant part of your Emacs config